# Use WebAssembly module compiled with Emscripten in Next JS

Tags: next.js, emscripten

I am trying to build a Next JS project with an imported WebAssembly module compiled using Emscripten.
The problem seems to be related to the WebPack loader being unable to import the `.wasm` module via the generated `.js`.
I would greatly appreciate some help.

My C++ file hello.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>

extern "C" {

int int_sqrt(int x) {
  return sqrt(x);
}

}
```

I compile using:

```
em++ hello.cpp -o "../v2/lib/wasm/test.js" -s MODULARIZE -s WASM=1 -s EXPORT_NAME="SZU" -s ENVIRONMENT="web" -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_int_sqrt -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=ccall,cwrap
```

I try to use the module in one of the components like so:

```
import SZU from "../../../../../../wasm/test";
var int_sqrt = SZU().cwrap("int_sqrt", 'number', ['number'])
```

When I run `npx next build` the build fails with:

```
Error: not compiled for this environment (did you build to HTML and try to run it not on the web, or set ENVIRONMENT to something - like node - and run it someplace else - like on the web?)
```

I expect to be able to build the project using `npx next build` then start the server with `npx next start` and be able to interact with functions exported in the `.wasm`/`.js` module files generated by Emscripten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [@lab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151192/lab) I realized my approach was wrong. This is the way I made my WASM module work:

1. This is my `hello.cpp` file. Important notice the `extern "C" {}` block:

```
#include <math.h>

extern "C" {

int int_sqrt(int x) {
  return sqrt(x);
}

}
```

2. I compile using em++ the destination is the `public` folder in next. We need to serve the `.wasm` and `.js` statically like [@lab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151192/lab) pointed out:

```
em++ hello.cpp -o "../v2/public/wasm/test.js" -s MODULARIZE -s WASM=1 -s EXPORT_NAME="SZU" -s ENVIRONMENT="web" -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_int_sqrt -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=ccall,cwrap
```

2. I load the Emscripten generated js file using the `next/script` tag like so:

```
<Script src="/wasm/test.js" strategy='beforeInteractive'/>
```

3. In the Component I want to use my WASM module I load it inside the `next/useEffect` hook, wrap it with Emscripten `cwrap` and store the function in a reference object using `next/useRef` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof (window as any).SZU === 'function' && WASM.current === null){
        console.log("loading WASM!");
        (window as any).SZU()
            .then((wasm: WASM) => {
                console.log("got WASM!");
                WASM.current = wasm;
                int_sqrt.current = WASM.current.cwrap("int_sqrt", "number", ["number"]);
            });
    }
}, []);
```

4. I can call the function later like so:

```
console.log(`Square root of 16 is ${int_sqrt.current(16)}`);
```

I hope this helps someone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The case for wasm is that it will compile into 2 files: a js file and a wasm file. The wasm file cannot be bundled into your app. You must serve it as a static asset (since it's basically binary code), and configure your path to align with your desired import.

Also you might want to ensure it work first. Try writing a nodejs script that import it and give it a test run. OR you can try import it into a nextjs API route, and invoke it via fetch from client-side and see if your compiled wasm work.

Comment: When I put `test.js` and `test.wasm` in the `public/wasm` folder I can load the module like so: `<Script src="/wasm/test.js" strategy='beforeInteractive'/>` and call the WASM functions like so in the DevTools console: `window.SZU().then(module => {console.log(module._int_sqrt(8))});` That works!

Comment: So the wasm module is compiled successfully and I can call my functions at runtime in the browser.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to load it in my React Components and use it in the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: You can likely just use the exact same code above with a window check + useRef to referencing the module